# functors unique up to self-equivalence of the source category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, tag-removed

Call two functors two functors $H,H':S\longrightarrow T$  *weakly equivalent*, or *equivalent up to a self-equivalence of the source category*, iff
there exists a self-equivalence of $s:S \longrightarrow S$ such that functors $H$ and $H'\circ s$ are equivalent.

> Can this property "weakly equivalent" be nicely reformulated in the language of higher category theory? or maybe homotopy theory?
>
> Are there theorems claiming that any two functors with certain properties (not involving choice) are weakly equivalent?

That is, for such a theorem to be interesting, the properties should not explicitly involve an arbitrary choice, e.g. it should not say: choose a topology, bijection, self-equivalence and then construct the functor in the following way. Rather, a functor should be described in terms of preserving some structure etc.

Below is the original question which was phrased very confusingly, it seems. I hope now it maybe is clearer.

Say a functor is "well-defined up to a self-equivalence of the source category"
by certain properties/definition/construction iff, well,
for any two functors $H,H':S\longrightarrow T$ with satisfying these properties/definition/obtained by this construction,
there exists a self-equivalence of $s:S \longrightarrow S$ such that functors $H$ and $H'\circ s$ are equivalent.

> Is there a nice way to reformulate this property
>   "a functor unique up to self-equivalence of the source category", say in the language of 2-categories?
>
> Are there any interesting examples of properties/definitions/constructions NOT involving arbitrary choice
>   and yet such that the functor is well-defined  up to a self-equivalence of source category ?

I am mostly interested to see an "algebraic" definition of a functor between "algebraic" categories which is well-defined up to self-equivalence but not well-defined.

Comment: A 'functor' which is not well defined is *not* a functor.

Comment: I don't think he means "well-defined" in the usual sense. On the other hand, "well-defined" here hasn't been exactly, um, well-defined -- the opening sentence is a bit slippery. But to give an example, I think he means that if a category $C$ has products but not *chosen* products, then "the product functor" $C \times C \to C$, while not specified, exists and is "defined well enough" since any two choices are canonically isomorphic. A property P of functors would be "well-defining" if any two functors satisfying P are isomorphic, e.g., a universal property P. (But the question needs work.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Then I shall just remove the opening sentence: it seems rather to confuse than clarify....Does the second paragraph seems unclear as well ? 

Comment: Todd Trimble: yes, that is what I mean....But I removed the sentence your comment refers to.

Comment: One problem seems to be that every functor is well-defined (in your sense, which you erased, but you mean the special case where $s$ is the identity) by *some* property. Given a functor $F: C \to D$, define property P on functors $G: C \to D$ by the condition that $G = F$ identically. Any two functors satisfying property P are canonically isomorphic. This silly example indicates that you probably need to sharpen what you really intend by "well-defined". 

Comment: Todd Timple: I am interested in the relation between functors : two functors H:S-->T and H':S-->T are "weakly equivalent" iff there is a self-equivalence s:S-->S such that H and $H'\circ s$ are equivalent. I wanted to ask whether there is a higher category theoretic view on this relation between functors? And I wanted to see an example of a class of functors where any two functors are weakly equivalent for non-trivial reasons; in other words, a theorem claiming that functors with certain properties are necessarily weakly equivalent. I shall update the question accordingly..Thank you! 

Comment: My answer was wrong.  I too quickly identified equivalent categories.

I'm voting the question up since I've learned from it already!

Really the question should be put one step more generally: is there an intrinsic definition of "a functor up to equivalence of the domain and codomain categories"?

Answer (score 4):

In short, this is equivalence of objects in the weak slice 2-category $\mathbf{CAT}/T$.

First recall the classical notion of slice *category*: given any category $\mathcal{C}$ and object $C$, there's a category $\mathcal{C}/C$ (called **$\mathcal{C}$ sliced over $C$**) whose objects are the maps in $\mathcal{C}$ with codomain $C$ and whose maps are commutative triangles.

When $\mathcal{C}$ is a 2-category, you can make the same sort of definition (so that any object $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ gives rise to a slice 2-category $\mathcal{C}/C$), but you now have a choice to make.  The objects of $\mathcal{C}/C$ are defined as before, but you could ask for the 1-cells in $\mathcal{C}/C$ to be strictly commutative triangles, or triangles that commute up to a specified invertible 2-cell, or triangles that commute up to a specified not-necessarily-invertible 2-cell (and then you have to decided which way it points).  In all cases, there's an obvious way to define the 2-cells of $\mathcal{C}/C$.

Let's take the "weak" or "pseudo" version of $\mathcal{C}/C$, in which the 1-cells are triangles that commute up to a specified invertible 2-cell.  Take two objects of $\mathcal{C}/C$, say $h\colon D \to C$ and $h'\colon D' \to C$.  In any 2-category, there's a notion of equivalence of objects.  In this case, $h$ and $h'$ are equivalent in $\mathcal{C}/C$ if and only if there's an equivalence $s\colon D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $h' \circ s \cong h$.

Applied to $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{CAT}$, this gives the notion of "weak equivalence" you mention.  (It just so happens that in your setting, the domains of $H$ and $H'$ are equal.)

Comment: Yes.  I wish I'd said that (instead of what I did say).

Comment: Thank you! I hoped for something like this. Now, the second part of my question: is there an example of something natural, an object of CAT/T, defined up to this equivalence ? That is, where it is important that you consider this equivalence rather then something stronger...But perhaps it is better stated as a separate question.

Comment: Tom Leinster: in fact, I am confused. What definition of a 2-category you are using; is it in your survey of definitions of n-categories? E.g. what is the 'specified invertible 2-cell' in CAT/T ? I assume T is the codomain category T of H:S-->T.  Sorry for bothering you about this. 

Comment: See for instance Kelly and Street's "Review of the elements of 2-categories" from 1974.  If you're interested in learning about n-categories in general, that's an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a mine observation (from old personal paper), may be can help. I hope my English is understandable*

I thought about this question in correlation to proposition 2.2.1 p.31 of "Indexed categories and its Applications" LNM 661:

Give a functor $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\to Cat$ (i.e. a strict indexed category) if its  objets and morphisms presheaf are representable:  $\mathcal{A}(C_0, -)\cong F_0$, $\mathcal{A}(C_1, -)\cong F_1$ by Yoneda lemma  domain, codomain the transformations $d_0:  F_1\Rightarrow F_0$, $d_1:  F_1\Rightarrow F_0$ ecc. describe a internal category $\underline{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and a isomorphism $F\cong [\mathcal{C} ]$ where $[\mathcal{C}]$ is the presheaf of (small) categories defined as $|[\mathcal{C}](A)|_0=\mathcal{A}(A, C_k)\ k=0, 1$ ecc.

But what if $F$ is a pseudo.functor? ($F_0$, $F_1$ aren't presheaves, for the composition we haven't the strict coherence, but accompanied by automorphisms on codomain..)
The authors of the reference above consider $F_0(A)$ as the class of (canonically) isomorphic object of $|F(A)|_0$, and for $F_1(A)$ as the class of (canonically) isomorphic morphisms (as objects of $F(A)^{\underline{2}}$). At first reading I seem that this reduction to "**pseudo-skeletons**"  avoid the trouble of the canonical isomorphisms. I remember that the *skeleton* of a (small) category is make by a chose of a object for any isomorphic call, and make the full subcategory. But how is related a small category $\mathcal{C}$ with its *pseudo-skeleton* $pS(\mathcal{C})$?

Of course we have the natural functor (make  the quotient maps) $\pi: \mathcal{C}\to pS(\mathcal{C})$, now, try to define a reciprocal (equivalence we hope) functor $P$, merely a "chose functor":  then $P$ map any object $\xi\in pS(\mathcal{C})$ to a  its representant $X_{\xi}\in \mathcal{C}$ with $[X_\xi]=\xi$, and any morphism $\alpha: \xi\to \xi'$ to a its representant $f_\alpha: X_\xi\to X_{\xi'}$ with $[f_\alpha]=\alpha$,

(observe that a different chose $g_{\xi}$ is related to $f_\xi$ by automorphisms on domain and codomain $X_\xi$, $X_{\xi'}$ this is a generalization to the initial question)

we can chose $P(1_\xi)=1_{X_\xi}$ of course, but in general $f_{\gamma\circ\xi}\neq f_{\gamma}\circ f_\xi$ but these are related by automorphisms on domain and codomain.

Then I consider 2-category $G(\mathcal{C})$ make as follow: take the usual skeleton $Sk(\mathcal{C})$, then for $f, g: X\to Y$ define 2-cell $f\Rightarrow g$ as a couple of isomorhisms $s: X\to X,\ t: Y\to Y$ with $t\circ f=g\circ s$ (with natural composition and identities) then I have a correct 2-equivalences (make by a 2-functor and a pseudo-functor)) from $G(\mathcal{C})$ and its local skeleton (take skeleton on Hom-categories) that is just the pseudo-skeleton  $pS(\mathcal{C})$ .